# Multitenancy on ASP.NET Core in DbContext with Azure B2C

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, multi-tenant

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web API application that connects to different databases depending on what organization the user is from.
The organization is stored as a string value in their user account in Azure AD B2C, and upon performing a request, I need that user's organization to be identified and the correct connection string chosen based on their organization.

However, I'm having trouble getting the user's 'userId' in my DbContext.
I have tried two different implementations but neither are working.

1. Within the 'ConfigureServices' method in my Startup.cs file I have specified the following:

   ```
        ...
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
   ```
2. I then declared the Interface with its Service:

   ```
    public interface IUserRepository
    {
       public void LogCurrentUser();
    }

   public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
   {
      private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

      public UserRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
      {
          _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
      }

      public void LogCurrentUser()
      {
          var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
      }
   }
   ```

3)And finally, on my DbContext, I attempt to draw the userId from the claim:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ApplicationTenantClient _tenant;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, 
        ITenantService tenantProvider, 
        IUserRepository userRepository, 
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
    {
        // Attempt (1)
        userRepository.LogCurrentUser();

        // Attempt (2)
        var userAccessor = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if(userAccessor != null)
        {
            var userId = userAccessor.Value;
        }
      
        _tenant = tenantProvider.GetTenant(); // <- ideally send userId here for lookup on AD Graph 
    }
    ...
```

After authenticating the user, then attempting to call an endpoint, the claim is empty:

First Result:
[image: Result from Service]

Second Result:
[image: Result from Accessor]

This is.. highly confusing, any help would be appreciated.

**Articles that I have attempted to follow**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0

https://www.koskila.net/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Please post the code as text

Comment: Sorry about that, I've done so now

Comment: Where are you setting the claims in cookie or JWT?

Comment: JWT, as it's utilizing Azure AD B2C